# Service Broker : Multiple sources and one target... The connection was closed

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

We try to setup a data replication with Service Broker. The topology is many sources sending data to one target.

Our solutions works with in one to one situation even when the faulty source is used...

When we use two sources, one a them (always the same) cannot be reach out and the reply is never sent... (the messages are correctly sent and receive by the target...)

The message in SQL Profiler is "*The connection was closed by the remote end, or an error occurred while receiving data: '64(The specified network name is no longer available.)*"

From the source point of view, the differences between our two sources are:

- the certificates, the sender services and the routes.

every other objets including queues, message types, contacts... are the same

Please let me know if you want the all SQL scripts

---

SSBdignose on server 1 :

Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.1600.1

Service Broker Diagnostic Utility

D  29925 LVICSV0003\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  Contract SBCTR_FLOW_ROWS does  not have the same definiton on the initiator and target

D  29974 LVICSV0002\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  The certificate CRT_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG_SOURCE_1 used by user USR_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG for dialog security is not deployed in the database.

D  29977 LVICSV0002\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  The user USR_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG from database DB_PMS_VILLAGE on LVICSV0003\DEV cannot be mapped into this database using certificates

D  29956 LVICSV0002\DEV                  The certificate used by server LVICSV0003\DEV for authentication is not deployed on server LVICSV0002\DEV. The Public role will be checked for CONNECT permission on the Service Broker endpoint on server LVICSV0002\DEV

D  29956 LVICSV0003\DEV                  The certificate used by server LVICSV0002\DEV for authentication is not deployed on server LVICSV0003\DEV. The Public role will be checked for CONNECT permission on the Service Broker endpoint on server LVICSV0003\DEV

3 Errors, 2 Warnings

---

SSB Diagnose on server 2 :

Microsoft SQL Server 10.50.1600.1

Service Broker Diagnostic Utility

D  29925 LVICSV0002\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  Contract SBCTR_FLOW_ROWS does  not have the same definiton on the initiator and target

D  29974 LVICSV0002\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  The certificate CRT_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG_SOURCE_1 used by user USR_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG for dialog security is not deployed in the database.

D  29977 LVICSV0002\DEV  DB_PMS_VILLAGE  The user USR_PMS_SERVICE_BROKER_DIALOG from database DB_PMS_VILLAGE on LVICSV0003\DEV cannot be mapped into this database using certificates

D  29956 LVICSV0003\DEV                  The certificate used by server LVICSV0002\DEV for authentication is not deployed on server LVICSV0003\DEV. The Public role will be checked for CONNECT permission on the Service Broker endpoint on server LVICSV0003\DEV

D  29956 LVICSV0002\DEV                  The certificate used by server LVICSV0003\DEV for authentication is not deployed on server LVICSV0002\DEV. The Public role will be checked for CONNECT permission on the Service Broker endpoint on server LVICSV0002\DEV

3 Errors, 2 Warnings

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the routes look like and if ssbdiagnose is telling you anything.

Comment: we have tryed several configurations, but always there is something wrong...

Comment: Of the things that ssbdiagnose told you, have you addressed any of them? It looks like mostly deploying certs. Also, there are a bunch of extended events relating to SB. Start trying to trace it that way (from both the initiator and target).